# What's the basic setup for an invoice solution

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

Say, I have a basic invoice, with the name `iv_i` where `i` is the number of the invoice. Each invoice can have `n` items that should be added via a Visualforce page.

The items later can come from a `related list`, but for this example free text should be enough.

Here is a quick wireframe:

[image]

**What would be the basic setup (Custom Object + Visualforce + Apex) for such an invoice solution?**

Comment: Very open-ended question?

Comment: @MartinPeters: No, I don't think so. I could not find any tutorials for such basic task on Force.com and it is a clear question that can have several answers with varying approaches.

Answer (score 1):

A typical invoice solution would have the `Invoice` object, possibly in a master-detail relationship to a `Customer` or `Account` record.

You'd then have an `Invoice_Line` object as a master-detail to `Invoice`.  Each `Invoice_Line` will have a quantity, per-unit price, formula to total the line, and a lookup to an `Item` object.  The `Invoice` can total the amount of each `Invoice_Line` and include fields for tax, shipping, etc.

Here's a [Developerforce tutorial](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Quick_Tutorial_3%3a_Build_a_Cloud_Database_%E2%80%94_Create_a_New_Object) you should take a look at, it includes an example of building an Invoice solution.  I also think that this [Visualforce workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf) uses an invoice app as an example.